# js file getting content from mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to get a .js file to be populated with content from a MySQL database.

I have a .php file that does all the MySQL stuff:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,
DATE_FORMAT(gig_dateTime, '%Y') as gigYear,
DATE_FORMAT(gig_dateTime, '%m') as gigMonth,
DATE_FORMAT(gig_dateTime, '%d') as gigDay,
DATE_FORMAT(gig_dateTime, '%H') as gigHour,
DATE_FORMAT(gig_dateTime, '%i') as gigMinute
FROM live
WHERE gig_dateTime > NOW()
ORDER BY gig_dateTime DESC");
$to_encode = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $to_encode[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($to_encode);
```

and then in the .js file I have the following:

```
$.getJSON('live-dates.php', function(data) {
    var myConcerts = [];
    $.each(data, function(index, d){            
        myConcerts.push(
            "{",
            "year:", d.gigYear, ",",
            "month:", d.gigYear, ",",
            "day:", d.gigYear, ",",
            "hour:", d,gigHour, ",",
            "minute:", d.gigMinute, ",",
            "latitude:", d.gig_lat, ",",
            "longitude:", d.gig_long, ",",
            "location:", d.gig_location, ",",
            "infoWindow:", d.gig_info, "",
            "}"
        );
    });
});
```

but on loading the page I get **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

In the index.php file that displays the .js file I have the following included:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/myconcerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible or am I going at it the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: Are you including jQuery?  Is it loading before you execute that function?

Comment: Why are you pushing the literal strings `{`, `,` and `}` onto `myConcerts`?

Comment: Which line is the error happening on? I suspect you've got lots of confused code, and you haven't shown us the actual place where the error is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to wrap the `$.getJSON(...)` with `$(function(){ /* $.getJSON() HERE */ });`, which is the same as `$(document).ready(...);`.

Comment: You only need to wrap in the `$(document).ready()` if you access DOM elements. It has nothing to do with accessing `$` itself.

Comment: Furthermore, if `$` is undefined, how will `$(function())` be able to call it?